# Text to Speech Converter not working

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I am trying to do text to speech converter using java code.And i am using freetts.jar to do this.I need to use this in my web application.

```
import com.sun.speech.freetts.*;
public class convert {
    private static final String VOICENAME="kevin";

    public static void call(){
    Voice voice;

    VoiceManager vm=VoiceManager.getInstance();
    System.out.println("come");
    voice=vm.getVoice(VOICENAME);

    voice.allocate();

    try{

        voice.speak("wellcome to my world");
        System.out.println("coming here good"); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
    public static void main(String agrs[]){

        call();


    }

}
```

In the above code was not working **voice.speak()** method was not working .I don't know why.can any one help me to fix this?

And also i need to know how to make the text to voice conversion  with own voice .
Thank you

Comment: "I need to use this in my web application." - I really doubt this will work out as intended. Using this code in a webapp, on whose speaker do you think the voice will appear? Secondly "Not working" is not a sufficient error description to help you. Please add stacktraces if available. Consider checking [ask] for improving the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code. you must have added only freetts.jar to your buildpath. It will give nullpointer exception.

**Add all the jars from the lib folder of freetts-1.2.2-bin to your buildpath.**

The same code worked for me.

try and tell me.

And for your implementing your own voice: check out these articles

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182881/Text-to-Speech?msg=5074134#xx5074134xx

http://www.acapela-group.com/voices/voice-replacement/faq-my-own-voice/

Answer (score 0):

I know i am posting it little late, but this may help someone. I tried the similar, and it worked for me. Please find the code below.

```
    package com.mani.texttospeech;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.speech.AudioException;
import javax.speech.Central;
import javax.speech.EngineException;
import javax.speech.EngineStateError;
import javax.speech.synthesis.Synthesizer;
import javax.speech.synthesis.SynthesizerModeDesc;
import javax.speech.synthesis.Voice;

/**
 *
 * @author Manindar
 */
public class SpeechUtils {

    SynthesizerModeDesc desc;
    Synthesizer synthesizer;
    Voice voice;

    public void init(String voiceName) throws EngineException, AudioException, EngineStateError, PropertyVetoException {
        if (desc == null) {
            System.setProperty("freetts.voices", "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
            desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.US);
            Central.registerEngineCentral("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
            synthesizer = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
            synthesizer.allocate();
            synthesizer.resume();
            SynthesizerModeDesc smd = (SynthesizerModeDesc) synthesizer.getEngineModeDesc();
            Voice[] voices = smd.getVoices();
            for (Voice voice1 : voices) {
                if (voice1.getName().equals(voiceName)) {
                    voice = voice1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
        }
    }

    public void terminate() throws EngineException, EngineStateError {
        synthesizer.deallocate();
    }

    public void doSpeak(String speakText) throws EngineException, AudioException, IllegalArgumentException, InterruptedException {
        synthesizer.speakPlainText(speakText, null);
        synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpeechUtils su = new SpeechUtils();
        su.init("kevin16");
//        su.init("kevin");
//        su.init("mbrola_us1");
//        su.init("mbrola_us2");
//        su.init("mbrola_us3");
        // high quality
        su.doSpeak("Hi this is Manindar. Welcome to audio world.");
        su.terminate();
    }
}
```

And add the below dependencies to your **pom.xml** file.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.sociaal</groupId>
            <artifactId>freetts</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Hope this will be helpful.